# Multiple min values from multiple groups in table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I tried multiple approaches so far, I have a large table (thousands of records) where I have various trips having some besides other values few different countries, and the duration of trips in days, and I want to **randomly select** given amount of random items containing random selection from given trips, containing the some of **shortest for each country**, but in some country the shortest trip is 8 days, elsewhere 12, ... etc

```
| country | duration | price | departure  | hotelname | otherData |
|     A   |    8     | 123   | 2013-06-19 | hotel A   | blah blah |
|     A   |   15     | 234   | 2013-06-20 | hotel A   | blah blah |
|     A   |   15     | 234   | 2013-06-20 | hotel B   | blah blah |
|     A   |   15     | 234   | 2013-06-20 | hotel C   | blah blah |
|     B   |    8     | 345   | 2013-06-21 | hotel D   | blah blah |
|     C   |   12     | 456   | 2013-06-22 | hotel E   | blah blah |
  ...
```

I need to build a random array having 6 records containing selection of trips, trying to **minimize** the displaying of more results from the same country (but allowed if not enough different countries is in table) and selecting randomly some record for each country having the **lowest duration for that country**.

The problem is some countries have the shortest trips having 8 days, elsewhere it is 11 days, so I could not make a simple:

```
where days<9
```

and also because at the end of season there may be very little trips causing having not enough result, I cannot do a:

```
group by country
```

My idea is selecting 6 records for each country, having the shortest duration available to that country using `order by duration ASC`, then having results from all countries reorder them all by `rand()` and select first 6.

Comment: Getting the shortest for each country is easy, but getting a random number where the duration is close to the shortest seems strange. How do you define which ones are sufficiently close to the min duration to count? If you can define that then it is possible, and just becomes and issue of efficiently getting random results from the appropriate record.

Comment: it simply should for each country find all - order by duration asc, rand() which should efectively randomize order only within the given duration (random order of all 8 days, then 9 days, ..) and repeat this selection for all countries providing one result consisting of all these partial results together ..

Comment: you wrote "[...] containing the some of **shortest** [...]". Is it "the sum of" or "some of the"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible way to do it, but probably not efficient.

```
SELECT country, duration, price, departure, hotelname, otherData
FROM 
(
    SELECT a.country, a.duration, a.price, a.departure, a.hotelname, a.otherData, 
    @counter := IF(a.country = @PrevCountry, @counter + 1, 0) AS CountryCounter,
    @PrevCountry := a.country
    FROM (SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY country, duration, RAND()) a
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @counter:=0, @PrevCountry:='') Sub2
) Sub1
WHERE CountryCounter < 6
```

This is using a user variable to get a sequence number of each record for a country, then using that sequence number to dispose of any records after the 1st 6 for each country.

Not tested.

Comment: ouuu seeing this I acknowledge I know little about mysql, will test this and even try to understand it ;)  thanx

Comment: No problem. I have just done a minor mod to it (having done a bit of testing on it). How it works is it uses a subselect to get the orders in the appropriate order, so country records will follow each other. The user variable (the ones that start with @) are initialised, and with each row the country is checked against the previous country. If it is the same then it adds 1 to the counter, if not it resets the counter to 0. Either way it stores the country back in the prev country variable. Then in the outer select it rejects any records where the counter isn't less than 6.